# Error on a JERSEY REST project (and tomcat)

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, neo4j, jersey

I met a surious problem when I want to develop an API to call an "exterior" method (this method is called "createClientNode" which is a simple request for neo4j).
Anyways, this is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>API</display-name>
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
<init-param> 
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
    <param-value>API</param-value> 
</init-param> 

<init-param> 
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name> 
    <param-value>true</param-value> 
</init-param> 
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 

</servlet>   

<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/API/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this my class :

```
package API;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import function.query.weceipt.GraphManagement;


@Path("/API")

public class MyService {    

@POST
@Path("/node")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Node createNode(@DefaultValue("default_id") @QueryParam("ID") String id) {

    GraphManagement gm = new GraphManagement();
    Node node = gm.createClientNode(id);

    return node;
}


@GET 
@Path("/node/{ID}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Node getNode(@PathParam("ID") String id) {

    GraphManagement gm = new GraphManagement();
    Node node = gm.getClientNode(id);

    return node;
}

@Path("/test")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public void afficher() {
    System.out.println("test");

}

}
```

the error that I get is "the Servlet jersey-serlvet is not available".
I have the impression that I have-perhaps- a problem with a specific JAR or Tomcat, but I coudn't find the cause of this problem. So, can anyone help me please because I tried a loooong time with this!

Comment: How are you packaging your war? You use `maven`? Please post the `pom.xml`, or the details anyway. Also, the full trace from tomcat might be helpful.

Comment: I think you shouldn't add any neo4j-server jars to your project. Only the ones for the embedded database like kernel, cypher*, lucene etc.

Comment: Also looking at your code, if you think you can return Nodes to be rendered as JSON I have to disappoint you, you have to do the transformation yourself.

Comment: And your methods always create a new graph-management while they should access a central one that's injected or accessed statically.

Comment: can you be explicite please. Mainly about how to parse the Neo4jobject (node here) to JSON. I don't have an idea how to do that honestly.